# Does the weak $L^p$-norm of $f_n$ tending to $0$ imply $\int_Bf_n\phi→0$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $f_n \in L^p(B)$ be a sequence where $B$ is some ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Assume that  $\|f_n\|_{L^p(B)} \rightarrow 0$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$, then for any $\phi \in C^\infty_0(B)$, applying Hölder we get
$$
\int_B f_n \phi \le \|f_n\|_{L^p(B)}\|\phi\|_{L^{p/(p-1)}(B)}.
$$
Thus, $\int_B f_n \phi \rightarrow 0$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Does the result remains true if we replace the condition $\|f_n\|_{L^p(B)} \rightarrow 0$ by $\|f_n\|_{L^p_w(B)} \rightarrow 0$? Here, $\|f\|_{L^p_w(B)}$ is the infimum of all constant $C$ such that
$$ \mathcal{L}^n \{ x \in B: |f(x) | > \alpha \} \le \dfrac{C^p}{\alpha^p} \quad (\forall \alpha >0)$$
is the weak $L^p$-norm of $f$ in $B$. This is. Do we have  $\int_{B} f_n \phi \rightarrow 0$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}\def\peq{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{}}$Denote $C_n = \|f_n\|_{L_{\mathrm{w}}^p}\ (n \geqslant 1)$. For any bounded and measurable $φ$ on $B$, suppose $M = \|φ\|_{L^∞}$. For $n \geqslant 1$,\begin{align*}
&\peq \left| \int\limits_B f_nφ \,\d x \right| \leqslant M \int\limits_B |f_n| \,\d x = M \int_0^{+∞} m(\{x \in B \mid |f_n(x)| > t\}) \,\d t\\
&= M\int_0^{C_n} m(\{x \in B \mid |f_n(x)| > t\}) \,\d t + M \int_{C_n}^∞ m(\{x \in B \mid |f_n(x)| > t\}) \,\d t\\
&\leqslant M \int_0^{C_n} m(B) \,\d t + M \int_{C_n}^∞ \frac{C_n^p}{t^p} \,\d t = M\left( m(B) + \frac{1}{p - 1} \right) · C_n,
\end{align*}
thus$$
\lim_{n → ∞} C_n = 0 \Longrightarrow \lim_{n → ∞} \int\limits_B f_nφ \,\d x = 0.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $p>1$. Let $1<q<p$ and $f\in L^{p,\infty}$. Then 
$$\int_B|f(x)|^q\mathrm dx=q\int_0^{+\infty}s^{q-1}\mathcal L\{t:|f(t)>s\}\mathrm dx\leqslant q\lVert f\rVert_{p,\infty}\left(\int_{1}^{\infty}s^{q-p-1}\mathrm ds+\mathcal L(B)\right).$$
In particular, the inclusion $L^{p,\infty}\to L^q$ is continuous.

In this context, we have $\lVert f_n\rVert_{L^q}\to 0$, hence we can use the same argument as in the OP.

Comment: Seeing again your solution, I think that you made a mistake. In fact, I believe that if $1<q<p$, and  $f \in L^p_{Weak}(B_1)$ then $f \in L^q(B_1)$, because
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{B_1}|f(x)|dx &=& q\int_0^\infty s^{q-1}|\{|f|>s\}|ds\\
&=& q\int_0^1 s^{q-1}|\{|f|>s\}|ds + q\int_0^\infty s^{q-1}|\{|f|>s\}|ds\\
&\le& q \int_0^1 s^{q-1}|B| ds + q\int_1^\infty s^{q-p-1}s^p|\{|f|>s\}|ds\\
&=& |B|+ \|f\|_{L^p_{Weak}(B_1)}q\int_0^1s^{q-p-1}ds\\
&=& |B|+ \|f\|_{L^p_{Weak}(B_1)}q\dfrac{1}{q-p}<\infty.\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: However, we do not have, $\|f\|_{L^q(B_1)}\rightarrow 0$ if $\|f\|_{L^p_{Weak}(B_1)}\rightarrow 0$. On the other hand, the only assumption that we have is that $\|f_n\|^p_{Weak}(B_1)\rightarrow 0$, this is
$$ s^p|\{|f_n|>s\}| \le \|f_n\|^p_{Weak}(B_1) < \infty.$$
Therefore, if we estimate
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{B_1}|f(x)|dx &\le &  \|f\|_{L^p_{Weak}(B_1)}q\int_0^\infty s^{q-p-1}ds\\
\end{eqnarray*}
The right hand side is not convergent. What do you think? Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, I think my argument is not quite accurate. However, since we are in the context of finite measure spaces, we can show that $L^{q,\infty}$, is for $q>1$, the space of functions for which $\sup_A\mu(A)^{1-\frac 1q}\int_A|f|d\mu$ is finite, where the supremum is taken over all the Borel subsets of $B$. From this, it's not hard to show the embedding. (I believed there was a more direct argument, but it seems it's not the case).